# Chrome Extension JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to deploy a html+jss+css project of a pattern password as a chrome extension. On my local machine the code works as expected. However when I test it as a chrome extension, the box in which the pattern is to be entered is not displayed.

Code Below :

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Pattern Lock Welcome Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jquery-script-menu">

    <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <h1 style="margin:150px auto 20px auto; text-align:center; color:#fff">Pattern Lock</h1>
    <div class="maincontainer">
        <h2 id="heading" class="heading">Please set your password</h2>
        <div id="patterncontainer" class="patterncontainer">
        </div>
   </div>
</body>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

welcome.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Pattern Lock</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="maincontainer">
    <h2 id="heading" class="heading">Homescreen</h2>
    <button id="lockScreen" class="button-lockscreen" onclick="window.location= './index.html';">Lock Screen</a><br /><br />
    <button id="resetPassword" class="button-reset" onclick="resetPassword()">Reset Password</a>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/homepage.js"></script>


</html>
```

homepage.js

```
function resetPassword() {
console.log("sdfsdf");
if (localStorage.getItem("password")) {
    alert("Pattern : "+localStorage.getItem("password"));
    localStorage.removeItem("password");
    successmessage("resetSuccess");
} else {
    emptyPassword();
}
};
(function checkPassword(){
if (!localStorage.getItem("password")) {
    emptyPassword();
}
}());

function successmessage(successcode) {
if (successcode == "resetSuccess") {
    alert("Pattern Reset Success!");
}
location.reload();
};

function emptyPassword() {
document.getElementById("resetPassword").style.display = "none";    
document.getElementById("lockScreen").innerHTML = "Set Password";
};
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var errorraised = false;
var passwordset = false;
var getClickStarted = false;
var autosubmit = true;
var password;
var centerX1;
var centerY1;
var curX = 0;
var curY = 0;
var getClickStarted = false;
var htmlLine;
var startpointnumber=0;
var endpointnumber=0;

(function checkIfPasswordIsSet() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("password")) {
        document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Enter pattern to unlock screen";
        passwordset = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "Please set your pattern";
    }
}());

(function generatebuttons(){
    var patterncontainer  = document.getElementById("patterncontainer");
    for (var i = 1; i <=9; i++) {
        var button = document.createElement("div");
        button.className = "button";
        button.id = "button" + i;
        patterncontainer.appendChild(button);

        startposition = document.getElementById("button" + i);
    }
}());

(function main(){
    if(!window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {

        $(".button").on("mousedown", function (event){

            if(!getClickStarted){

                getClickStarted = true;

                var offset1 = $("#" + event.target.id).position();

                centerX1 = offset1.left + $("#" + event.target.id).innerWidth()/2 + 20.5; //22.5 is the margin of the button class
                centerY1 = offset1.top + $("#" + event.target.id).innerHeight()/2 + 20.5;

                //console.log("centerX1 " + centerX1);
                //console.log("centerY1 " + centerY1);

                if (event && event.preventDefault){
                       event.preventDefault();
                }

                $("#" + event.target.id).removeClass("button").addClass("activebutton");

                password = event.target.id.split("button").join("");
                startpointnumber = event.target.id.split("button").join("");

                //console.log("startpointnumber " + startpointnumber);

                addline(startpointnumber, centerX1, centerY1); //initiating a moving line
            }

        });

        $(document).bind("mousemove", function(event) {
            if (getClickStarted){ //to avoid mousemove triggering before click

                if (event && event.preventDefault){
                   event.preventDefault();
                }

                curX = event.clientX - $("#patterncontainer").offset().left;
                curY = event.clientY - $("#patterncontainer").offset().top;

                var width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(curX - centerX1, 2) + Math.pow(curY - centerY1, 2)); //varying width and slope
                var slope = Math.atan2(curY - centerY1, curX - centerX1)*180/3.14;

                //setting varying width and slope to line
                $("#line" + startpointnumber).css({"width": + width +"px", "height": "4px", "transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)", "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)", "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)"});

                //if button is found on the path
                $(".button").bind("mouseover", function(e) {

                    endpointnumber = e.target.id.split("button").join("");

                    if (startpointnumber != endpointnumber) {
                        if (e && e.preventDefault){
                           e.preventDefault();
                        }

                        if (e.target.className == "button") {
                            $("#" + e.target.id).removeClass("button").addClass("activebutton");
                        } else {
                            $("#" + e.target.id).removeClass("activebutton").addClass("duplicatebutton");
                        }

                        password += e.target.id.split("button").join("");
                        // endpointnumber = e.target.id.split("button").join("");

                        $("#line" + startpointnumber).attr("id", "line" + startpointnumber + endpointnumber);

                        var offset2 = $("#" + e.target.id).position();

                        var centerX2 = offset2.left + $("#" + e.target.id).innerWidth()/2 + 20.5;  //20.5 is the margin of activebutton class
                        var centerY2 = offset2.top + $("#" + e.target.id).innerHeight()/2 + 20.5;

                        var linewidth = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerX2 - centerX1, 2) + Math.pow(centerY2 - centerY1, 2));
                        var lineslope = Math.atan2(centerY2 - centerY1, centerX2 - centerX1)*180/3.14;

                        $("#line" + startpointnumber + endpointnumber).css({"width": + linewidth +"px", "transform": "rotate(" + lineslope + "deg)", "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + lineslope + "deg)", "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + lineslope + "deg)"});

                        startpointnumber = endpointnumber;
                        centerX1 = centerX2;
                        centerY1 = centerY2;

                        addline(startpointnumber, centerX1, centerY1);
                    }

                });
            }

            $("#patterncontainer").on("mouseup", function (event){

                if(getClickStarted) {
                    if (event && event.preventDefault){
                       event.preventDefault();
                    }

                    $("#line" + startpointnumber).remove();

                    if (autosubmit) {
                        formsubmit();
                    }
                }
                getClickStarted = false;
            });
        });

    } else {
        alert ("INTERNET EXPLORER NOT SUPPORTED!!");
    }
}());

function addline(startpointnumber, centerX1, centerY1){
    var htmlLine = "<div id='line" + startpointnumber + "' class='line' style='position: absolute; top: " + centerY1 + "px; \
                left: " + centerX1 + "px; -webkit-transform-origin: 2px 2px; -moz-transform-origin: 2.5% 50%; background-color: #FFF;'></div>"

    $("#patterncontainer").append(htmlLine);
}

function formsubmit(){

    var digits = getlength(password);
    if(digits<5) {
        raiseerror("lengthTooSmall");
    }

    checkduplicatedigits(password);

    if (errorraised == false && passwordset == false) {
        localStorage.setItem("password", password);
        successmessage("patternStored");
    }
    else if ( errorraised == false && passwordset == true) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("password") == password) {
            successmessage("screenUnlocked");
            window.location = "./welcome.html";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            raiseerror("IncorrectPattern");
        }
    }
};

function getlength(number) {
    return number.toString().length;
};

function checkduplicatedigits(number) {
    var digits = getlength(number);
    numberstring = number.toString();
    var numberarray = numberstring.split("");
    var i; var j;
    for (i = 0; i < digits-1; i++) {
        for (j = i+1; j < digits; j++) {
            if(numberarray[i] == numberarray[j]) {
                raiseerror("repeatedEntry");
            }
        }
    }
};

function successmessage(successcode) {
    if(successcode == "screenUnlocked") {
        alert("You have unlocked the screen!");
    }
    if (successcode == "patternStored") {
        alert("Your pattern is stored. Thanks.");
        passwordset = true; 
    }
    if (successcode == "Success") {
        alert("Pattern Reset Success!");
    }
    location.reload();
};

function raiseerror(errorcode) {
    if(!errorraised){
        errorraised = true;
        if (errorcode == "lengthTooSmall") {
            alert("The pattern is too short. Please try again.");
        }
        if (errorcode == "repeatedEntry") {
            alert("You cannot use the same number twice. Please try again.");
        }
        if (errorcode == "IncorrectPattern") {
            alert("The entered pattern in incorrect. Please try again.");
        }
        if (errorcode == "emptyPassword") {
            alert("You did not set the password to reset it.");
        }
        location.reload();
    }
};
});
```

and lastly this is my manifest.json :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "GRAphical Pass",
  "description": "THIS IS SPARTA!!!!!!",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)
[Expected(this is what I get on my machine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmwuk.png)

But deploying it as an extension :
[this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Yoj.png)

Comment: I have a jquery.min.js file too but it was too long to properly format and post here.

Comment: try adding `welcome.html` to your `web_accessible_resources` manifest object since you are trying to access that resource in your popup script

Comment: @Daniel_L I tried it but it made no difference. Thanks for trying to help out though :)

Comment: are you even able to switch your popup location like that? that would be my first guess as to why it's working locally but not in a crx

Comment: Ugh, sorry I'm so lazy but you can resolve all the issues after reading the short [extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), especially the architecture, content scripts, and the part that says that all scripts on extension's pages should be included in the package.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest removing : $(document).ready(function(){

from your scripts and adding

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
  "<all_urls>"
],
"js": ["homepage.js","script.js"]
}
],
```

to your manifest along with the following CSP :

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: Nonsensical answer (won't solve even half of the problems, zero explanation) and very suspicious name collision - potential sockpuppet.

Comment: @Siddharth Sharma  It did the initial task and now I'm able to get the script.js running properly, but the homepage.js is still not working

Comment: @Xan Your name looks suspicious to me too. The first person that actually tried to help and you called their answer nonsensical. I'm sorry but that's just too rude and non-sensical or not it helped UNLIKE Yours.

Comment: I'll concede the possibility that the name being the same is just a coincidence. I will, however, maintain the opinion that this answer is not a good one because of the lack of explanation. And that it only solves half of the problems - yet you said "worked like a charm". That's suspicious - people can use tactics like this to inflate reputation. Hence, my comment.